# sentence meaning "I'm not telling people generally yet."

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I'm not telling people generally yet.
>   OK, mum's the word!

In here, what do you mean by "I'm not telling people generally yet." ?
(especially "generally")

My guess is as follows
1) I'm not telling = firm intention / definite decision?
2) yet = in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not telling people generally yet.

"Generally " here means "to most people". "Yet" here means "still" or "up to now". The second person agrees to keep something a secret.

Comment: Can I say "have not been telling" or "have not told" or "do not tell"? And why do you say "I am not telling" (present continuous tense)? Any special meaning or difference?  Thank you